# adder in binary addition: XOR instead of OR gate

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra, adder, binary

I am just a newbie starting out in electronics with no experience.

1. Why do we need XOR and AND gate for the binary adder? is there any particular reason why only these two specific gates are needed and used?
2. As I understand OR gate adds values (boolean algebra - X = A+B then why we use XOR gate at the beginning of the circuit and not OR gate?

Comment: What's 1 + 1? What's 1 OR 1? Are they the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two outputs from a half-adder. These are ***sum*** and ***carry***. Assuming **A** and **B** are the inputs, then their output tables look like this:

$$
\begin{align*}
{\begin{array}{c|c}
  { Sum }
& {
    \begin{smallmatrix}
        B\\
        \begin{array}{cc}
            \overbrace{\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\end{array}}
        \end{array}
    \end{smallmatrix}
  }\\
\hline
  {
    \begin{smallmatrix}
        \begin{array}{r}
           A \left\{
               \begin{array}{c}
                 0\\
                 1
               \end{array}
             \right.\\
       \end{array}
    \end{smallmatrix}
  }
& {
     \begin{smallmatrix}
         \begin{array}{c}
             \left.\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right.\\
         \end{array}
     \end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}}
&&&&
{\begin{array}{c|c}
  {Carry }
& {
    \begin{smallmatrix}
        B\\
        \begin{array}{cc}
            \overbrace{\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\end{array}}
        \end{array}
    \end{smallmatrix}
  }\\
\hline
  {
    \begin{smallmatrix}
        \begin{array}{r}
           A \left\{
               \begin{array}{c}
                 0\\
                 1
               \end{array}
             \right.\\
       \end{array}
    \end{smallmatrix}
  }
 & {
     \begin{smallmatrix}
         \begin{array}{c}
             \left.\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\0&1\end{array}\right.\\
         \end{array}
     \end{smallmatrix}
   }
\end{array}}
\end{align*}
$$

You could just put the above tables together into a single table that shows both the sum and the carry-out. Something like this:

$$
\begin{align*}
{\begin{array}{c|c}
  { }
& {
    \begin{matrix}
        B\\
        \begin{array}{cc}
            \overbrace{\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\end{array}}
        \end{array}
    \end{matrix}
  }\\
\hline
  {
    \begin{matrix}
        \begin{array}{r}
           A \left\{
               \begin{array}{c}
                 0\\
                 1
               \end{array}
             \right.\\
       \end{array}
    \end{matrix}
  }
& {
     \begin{matrix}
         \begin{array}{c}
             \left.\begin{array}{cc}^00&^01\\^01&^10\end{array}\right.\\
         \end{array}
     \end{matrix}}
\end{array}}
\end{align*}
$$

Either way you draw it, the result is the same. The ***sum*** has the same truth table as an **XOR** does and the ***carry*** has the same truth table as an **AND** does.

It's that simple.

Don't get "mired" into words. Look at the behavior, not the words people use for things. You can know the name of a bird in every language on Earth and not know a ***single thing*** about the bird. The way you learn about the bird is to ***watch it*** and see how it ***behaves***.

If someone says **OR** is (+), that's just a symbol that is supposed to imply a meaning to you -- but only if you've been trained about that meaning. In this case, it means *inclusive* as in, *"If **A** is true, or if **B** is true, or if both **A** and **B** are true, then the **result** is true."* Please note that this includes a special case where both are true! So the inclusive-OR, aka (+), is a little different than addition.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, but here's my confusion, why can't we use an OR + AND gate for binary adder? everywhere I see, it an XOR + AND gate combination.

Comment: @josh2020 jonk answered the part of your question that's not based on unfounded claims. "everywhere I see": Well, that seems to be a very selective choice. Due to the CMOS nature of most technology, it's really more NAND + NOR gates. Exactly as said in my answer: your claim that it's "always" XOR + AND is plain wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I got it.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we need XOR and AND gate for the binary adder? is there any particular reason why only these two specific gates are needed and used?

You can build the same functionality with other gates, too. There's more than one way to form the same logic expression – there might be technologically optimal ones, but the XOR/AND one isn't necessarily *the* optimal solution for every technology (on CMOS logic wafers, for diode-to-diode logic wafers, in discrete construction on breadboard, in an FPGA: All these things will lead to preference of different methods to implement the same operation).

So, you don't *need* to use exactly these two types of gates. It is *one* way, of many.

You will meet de Morgan's rules, soon. There you'll see how an inverter (which you can build out of XOR and constant 1, for example) can convert AND-terms to OR-terms and vice versa.

But: **only** OR + AND can't work to form arbitrary logic operations. You can't form an inverter with that. You need some way to combine two inputs and a way to invert, and then *any* logic expression can be built; your AND+OR choice is among the very few that *won't* work.

> As I understand OR gate adds values (boolean algebra - X = A+B then why we use XOR gate at the beginning of the circuit and not OR gate?

Not quite sure what you're referring to - as mentioned above, there's more than one way to solve that, so we don't know how *your* adder looks like. What we can say is "if that XOR wasn't there, it wouldn't work as intended"; but that really doesn't help you, sorry.